# Can't Play Video using android default video player using intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-videoview

My Android Device can play directly the same Video MP4 and AVI Video Files but while using source code, it is giving me an error  "Can't Play this Video" after a progress dialog box with message of "Loading Video"..
I am using both the ways:
1. First Method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.parse("http://localhost/h.mp4");
                    intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/*");
                    startActivity(intent);
```

1. Second Method:

   ```
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
       intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivity(intent);
   ```

ANY HELP ?

Comment: MediaController mediacontroller = new ediaController(MultiRes.this);
mediacontroller.setAnchorView(vv);
Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
vv.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
vv.setVideoURI(video);
vv.requestFocus();
vv.start();

Answer (score 1):

You can try `VideoView`.  [(Documentation)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)

```
try{
      VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);         
      MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
      mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
      // Set Audio/Video
      String strfilename = "http://localhost/h.mp4";
      Uri video = Uri.parse(strfilename);
      videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
      videoView.setVideoURI(video);
      videoView.start();   
} 
catch (Exception e) {
//Handle Errors
}
```

**EDIT** 
Android is also picky about the way videos are encoded when using videoView. (See below quote from [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html))

> For video content that is streamed over HTTP or RTSP, there are additional requirements:
>
> •For 3GPP and MPEG-4 containers, the moov atom must precede any mdat
>   atoms, but must succeed the ftyp atom. 
> •For 3GPP, MPEG-4, and WebM
>   containers, audio and video samples corresponding to the same time
>   offset may be no more than 500 KB apart. To minimize this audio/video
>   drift, consider interleaving audio and video in smaller chunk sizes.

Comment: @Raheel Attempt with a random youtube URL to begin tracing to the root of the issue.

Comment: unfortunately, youtube is blocked in Pakistan

Comment: See about a random video that is posted somewhere else. Do you get any different errors?

Comment: I have tried a lot, it just played a 3gp file from NET but some other 3gp are still not being played

Comment: @Raheel See EDIT. playing from an http source makes android picky.

Comment: Using http or just playing it directly? I'm out of answers :(

Comment: using http, it works fine directly using device...but not from my app code

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml don't forget to also add -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

so that it can access the http.